# How to have a multi value parameter text box in SSRS that also allows blanks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that the user wants to be able to search upon multiple sites as supposed to just the one site that the report usually accepts.

If they don't enter a site in the parameter text box then the report searches for all sites.

I've handled this successfully within my SQL query in the where clause as shown below

> WHERE
>   ( ( LEN(@ProjectId) > 0 AND  p.ProjectId = @ProjectId ) OR     ( LEN(@ProjectId) =
>   0 ) )

This worked fine for searching just the one site or all sites if they didn't enter a value.

They want to be able to enter multiple sites and split them with a comma.

I handled this within my SSRS report as defining the parameter in my data set to be

> =JOIN(Parameters!ProjectId.Value, ",")

However this doesn't work for blank values or null values as expected.

I've done some fancy expressions to try and get round this like

> =IIF(ISNothing(Parameters!ProjectId.Value), "", JOIN(Parameters!ProjectId.Value))

To set the parameter passed to the SQL query to be blank and not to do the join if there isn't a value encountered.

Basically I want to know if there is a way I can have a multi set parameter split by commas but passed as a blank if a value is not chosen.

at the moment I've tried setting the parameter to allow multivalues which hasn't worked either I get the error message as shown below

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using the check box functionality of the parameters tab in the report? In the parameters tab the user would be able to select multiple locations and blank values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set up your multivalue parameter:

[image]

Then within your Dataset define a new parameter, in this instance I have called it `@PCount`:

[image]

`@PCount` is defined with the expression:

```
=IIF(Parameters!P1.Count=0 Or 
    (Parameters!P1.Count = 1 And Parameters!P1.Value(0) = ""),
        0,
        Parameters!P1.Count)
```

This will return 0 if no values are entered, or a blank value is entered. Then your query becomes something like:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM YourTable
WHERE ProjectID IN (@P1)
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM YourTable
WHERE @PCount = 0
```

You could do this with `OR`, as follows:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM YourTable
WHERE ProjectID IN (@P1)
OR @PCount = 0
```

But I think this is more likely to encounter performance issues.